# MySQL Double Order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Is there a better way to write

```
SELECT users.id FROM `users`,`profiles` WHERE users.id = profiles.id && 
profiles.zipcode = '$zipcode' && users.id != '1' && users.id != '2'
&& profiles.picture != '' ORDER BY users.last_activity DESC LIMIT 0,11
```

(The code above is suppose to find all the users with a certain zipcode, and order them by the last_activity timestamp)

Also, is there anyway to sort it by last_activity and gender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id 
FROM `users`
JOIN `profiles` ON users.id = profiles.id 
WHERE profiles.zipcode = '$zipcode' 
  AND users.id NOT IN (1,2)
  AND profiles.picture != '' 
ORDER BY users.last_activity DESC, users.gender 
LIMIT 0,11
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN `profiles` ON users.id = profiles.id WHERE profiles.zipcode = '53511' A' at line 3

Comment: I spaced, I put gender in the profiles table. I'm tired lol anyways the error is still the same after I changed that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add gender:

```
ORDER BY users.last_activity DESC, users.gender
```

Note that ordering by the second one (in this case `gender`) will only happen if two users have the same `last_activity` value. Consider it a "tie-breaker" ordering.

Comment: @ShaneLarson you can also optionally specify the search order for each  i.e. users.last_activity DESC, users.gender ASC